# GetByteCount shows up negative, but it's not

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, binarywriter

so i am trying to get ByteCount from a litview subitem, but it always shows up negative error: 
[Argument OutOfRangeException was unhandled: 'count' mustn't be negative, Parameter name: count]
this is the code line i get the error on:

```
bw.Write(enc.GetBytes(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text + (new string('\0',dbytecnt - enc.GetByteCount(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text)))));
```

i tried this:

```
 if (enc.GetByteCount(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text) > 0)
                {
                    bw.Write(enc.GetBytes(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text + (new string('\0',dbytecnt - enc.GetByteCount(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text)))));
                }
```

does not work, and even made the if condition to be '> -1', same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` on parameter `count`. It's probably the string constructor which throws this exception, not `GetByteCount`.

It means that the result of the subtraction `dbytecnt - enc.GetByteCount(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text)` is negative.

Try this:

```
if (dbytecnt - enc.GetByteCount(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text) > 0)
{
    bw.Write(enc.GetBytes(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text + (new string('\0',dbytecnt - enc.GetByteCount(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text)))));
}
```